# Animating images one after the other

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

Am trying to add imageViews onto a table layout dynamically and my requirement is that the images in the imageView have to be animated one after the other and all the image should retain on the view itself.

But the problem is the images are not getting animated one after the other rather the whole set of image fades in at once. But I want the images to fade-in one after the other which is not happening.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess u want to show 3 different images one after the other,right??

Comment: Not 3 images... The number of images is dynamic. The number of images to be shown and animated is entered in the first screen. it is passed onto the second screen where the images are appearing with fade-in animation at once for all the images. But i want to have image by image fade in animation. Thats my requirement. Thanks Error Handler.

Comment: one the First screen are u calling the images from somewhere.... i mean from the drawables?

Comment: u can use all the images from the first screen into an array and use it using put extra and get it in the next activity and then loop it accordingly

Comment: Am calling the image from the drawables.. and the number passed in the first screen the img should appear that much of time. So is the problem

Comment: correct me if i m wrong.U have a edit text where u but some random number and u want the image to be shown that many times.

Comment: Yeah... Exactly.. thats what I need to do.. In addition to that each image when they appear have to get animated one after the other.For me the whole set of images is getting animated. So thats the problem

Comment: then use the code that i have written for animation of images using the handler and try to use putextra & getextra..

Comment: Null pointer exception. If you don't mind, can you please post the whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using AsyncTask add images to the view one by one .

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
            int a =0;
            for (Integer row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

                tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                for (Integer col = 0; col < img; col++) {

                    image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    android.view.animation.Animation anim = animate(a);
                    /*android.view.animation.Animation anim = AnimationUtils
                                .loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadein);*/
                    image.startAnimation(anim);
                    image.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
                    tableRow.addView(image);
                    a++;
                }
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            }
            VSC.addView(tableLayout);
            HSC.addView(VSC);
            setContentView(HSC);
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestion for you that you can start with android `ViewFlipper` for making Animation like images to fade in and out .Search on ViewFlipper Example that will help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks Herry.. But it animates image by image na!!

Comment: Yes, in `ViewFlipper` all child which you will add it flip with animation that you have applied for fade in and out.

Comment: Am trying to implement it for the dynamically added imageViews. Once i get the desired solution, its my pleasure to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure there is solution you can create number of image-frames as per your animation requirements and you can then club those images in drawable folder.Then use animation like this.
`<animation-list

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/imvControl"
    android:oneshot="false"> <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>`

For more info go through [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App). 
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My requirement is the images have to be added dynamically. In the first activity i have to specify a number for images and as well as the rows. the intent has to be passed and in the second screen the number of images have to be appeared at the specified number of rows by one by one animation. I have taken table layout and all is done except for the animation of each image one after the other. Am not able to accomplish that. i even used addView(image,position); But its of no use.. So please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Define a class which extends Animation and mention you can make swapping the images using ViewFlipper as Herry said

Answer (score 0):

```
 t1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                int i =4;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(i<0){
                        i=4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Message m=new Message();
                    m.arg1=i;
                    imgHandler.sendMessage(m);
                    i--;
                    }
                }
            }, 0,1000);
 Handler imgHandler=new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {



            imgLogo.setImageDrawable(images[msg.arg1]);             

        };
```

I used this code to show images sequentially one after the other